# What does the ColdFusion framework "fusebox" do exactly?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, fusebox

I have a assignment for school and I need to use the Fusebox framework on my ColdFusion website. But why do I need to use it? And what are the benefits?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Fusebox](http://www.fusebox.org/) is a [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework for building application with the ColdFusion programming language. However, it is horribly outdated and hasn't been in development for quite some time. I'm surprised that you're being asked to use it for class when there are much more modern MVC frameworks available for ColdFusion.

[ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/) and [Framework 1](http://fw1.riaforge.org/) are much more modern implementations of MVC for CFML applications. It won't hurt you to use FuseBox for class, you'll learn the basics of MVC and how to structure your application. However, once you start building a larger application, try using either of these newer frameworks. You'll have a much better time with them.

As for why you need to use it, the question is not, "Why use FuseBox", but "Why use MVC?"

To quote the article from Wikipedia,

> Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing user interfaces. It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user. The central component, the model, consists of application data, business rules, logic and functions. A view can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants. The third part, the controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.

In other words, MVC gives you an excellent way to structure and separate your application code. You're probably used to building CF apps where queries, logic and UI are all in the same file. As your applications grow larger, this will cause duplication of code and other issues that can be easily addressed with an MVC framework.

Comment: Thanks you really helped me out and i will definitely use coldbox in the future!

Comment: Btw - did your school really insist on Fusebox? If so, please be sure to let them know what iKnowKungFoo said about about it being outdated. They are doing a disservice to their students on forcing an outdated framework.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I'm not surprised at all.  At my kids high school they still insist on using frames for their html class.  I don't mean just once, but for the entire course...  The school created the class about 4 years ago, but some how they chose a book that was ancient to teach the class.

Answer (score 2):

Fusebox may be out of date but it is not a bad system. It was used in many projects for many years. In fact it is a great tool for learning how to structure a software project because its principles can easily be understood even for newbies - the Fusebox structure is intuitive and can be taught in 10 minutes. If I were a teacher, I'd always start with something simple! Fusebox can be used to convey basic MVC ideas. Then if people want to learn more complex and contemporary methods, they can look at Coldbox which is way less intuitive

Comment: As a loooon-time user of Fusebox, I have to agree with this answer. Fusebox, for as old and rickety as it may seem, covers the, MVC basics extremely well.